# Documentation for chamferMatching in OpenCV 2.4 C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm looking for documentation on the chamferMatching method from the OpenCV 2.4 C++. The OpenCV implementation given in /OpenCV-2.4.0/samples/cpp/chamfer.cpp  which only uses the first four parameters. There are a total of 14 parameters which can be set which include:

Parameters:

```
img (Cv::Mat)

templ (Cv::Mat)

results (Std::Vector::Std_Vector_Cv_Point)

cost (Std::Vector::Float)

templ_scale (Double) (defaults to: 1)

max_matches (Fixnum) (defaults to: 20)

min_match_distance (Double) (defaults to: 1.0)

pad_x (Fixnum) (defaults to: 3)

pad_y (Fixnum) (defaults to: 3)

scales (Fixnum) (defaults to: 5)

min_scale (Double) (defaults to: 0.6)

max_scale (Double) (defaults to: 1.6)

orientation_weight (Double) (defaults to: 0.5)

truncate (Double) (defaults to: 20)
```

If anyone can point me out to an example or documentation which explains each of these parameters it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6229213/1652461) help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spent many days looking for an answer to the same question of yours but I didn't find any. The best clarification I got so far is from the original paper of fast directional chamfer matching:

[Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5539837)

[http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~mingyliu/papers/liu_cvpr2010.pdf](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/%7Emingyliu/papers/liu_cvpr2010.pdf)

img (Cv::Mat) **The test image**

templ (Cv::Mat) **The template which contains the shape you are looking for in the test image**

results (Std::Vector::Std_Vector_Cv_Point) **points vector which contains the matched point in the test image**

cost (Std::Vector::Float) **floats vector of the match cost for each result**

templ_scale (Double) (defaults to: 1) **magnification of the template image. not that it is Reciprocal**

max_matches (Fixnum) (defaults to: 20) **how many results you want**

min_match_distance (Double) (defaults to: 1.0) **what is the (maximum) matching cost you allow**

pad_x (Fixnum) (defaults to: 3) **pad X, of the search window**

pad_y (Fixnum) (defaults to: 3) **pad Y, of the search window**

scales (Fixnum) (defaults to: 5) **how many scales you want to use for the template**

min_scale (Double) (defaults to: 0.6) **obvious**

max_scale (Double) (defaults to: 1.6) **obvious**

orientation_weight (Double) (defaults to: 0.5) **by what percentage you want the orientation of a pixel to contribute in the cost calculation, default is 50%**

truncate (Double) (defaults to: 20) **the threshold at which the distance will be truncated (using threshold()**

Comment: After reading the implementation of Chamfer Matching, I realized that the truncate is simply the threshold at which the distance will be truncated (using threshold() ).