# Python OpenCV chamerMatching function reference

Tags: python, opencv, crash

I have searched everywhere and I find it truly amazing that there is no reference on the chamerMatching function, especially in Python. Someone else also had the same problem with [no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229326/documentation-for-chamfermatching-in-opencv-2-4-c):

I don't really want to know about the algorithm - I know how the algorithm works - I want to know how to call it in Python and retrieve the costs, results and bestfit. I have tried the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret, frame = cap.read()
frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (13, 13), 0)
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frame = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(frame,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

templ = cv2.imread("template.png",cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

cannyframe = cv2.Canny(frame,5,50,apertureSize=3)
cannytempl = cv2.Canny(templ,5,50,apertureSize=3)

cv2.imshow("cannyframe",cannyframe)
cv2.imshow("cannytempl", cannytempl)

cv2.waitKey(0)

#The line below, and NOT any other line, crashes the program
cv2.chamerMatching(cannytempl,cannyframe)
```

All of it runs fine except the final call to the chamerMatching function which causes the python interpreter to crash and stop working for some reason with a message that looks like this:

[image: Python crash window]

With absolutely **zero** documentation on the function, I can't figure out why.

**EDIT:**
The code above now includes all the required lines to run and below is template.png.

[image: template.png]

Comment: Ok, I've edited in the image for you, so don't worry

Comment: Thank you. That's better. And now.... we wait.... :)

Comment: You may want to attach `template.png.` Also, please give code that can actually be run, namely, your code above gives `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 16, in <module>
    ret, frame = cap.read()
NameError: name 'cap' is not defined
` See [ask]

Comment: I've edited the code to work as a standalone (although it still crashes because of the chamerMatching function, everything else works). I've also provided template.png. Any ideas now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if you still need this information. But I also needed chamfer matching for my research. And here's what I found after encountering the same dilemma as you've had.

http://code.opencv.org/issues/3602

:)

Comment: Wow, that's a long time later, but thanks for replying! I ended up using template matching which is isn't as robust as chamfer matching, but it works. But I would still like to get the chamfer working. I went to the link you posted, but couldn't make out anything that can help solve the problem... Any further comments please?

Comment: I actually just did what was said. I located the source code of chamfer matching within opencv and commented out this line delete templates[i];. After which, i just recompiled it. And then, it worked :)

Comment: Thanks again for your response. Oh ok I see. Unfortunately, I'm using Python and found that using pre-compiled libraries from Christoph Gohkle's page worked best. Compiling from source is not a direction I want to go. But thanks a LOT! I'll accept the answer. And good luck with your thesis.

Comment: I am wanting to do something similar, five years later. The link does not work anymore. Can anyone help me with any reference for Chamer matching in Python? Thanks