# chamfer distance transform for skeletonization

Tags: python, image-processing

are there any functions or libraries implemented in python for computing the image skeleton (skeletonization) using chamfer distance transform?

the following link is an example of chamfer distance transform:
http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~palagyi/skel/chamfer34.gif

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437688/how-to-use-chamfer-matching-algorithm-for-finding-similar-images ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question was not clearly phrased. Chamfer distance is the distance between two curves or two binary images

Say you have two curves.

- Curve A
- Curve B

The simplest way to calculate the Chamfer transform is convert curve A into [Distance Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) in a image. Then use the distances to calculate the nearest distance between each point in Curve A and points of curve B.

In other words, the sum of closest point distances between both curves or binary images.

#### Sample Code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# for Chamfer Distance between two curves
p_a - n x 2 numpy array
p_b - n x 2 numpy array
image_shape - (h, w) tuple
def chamfer(p_a, p_b, image_shape):
    mask = np.ones(image_shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8) * 255
    mask[p_a[:, 1].astype(int), p_a[:, 0].astype(int)] = 0
    dist = cv2.distanceTransform(mask, cv2.DIST_L2, 3,  dstType=cv2.CV_32F)
    return dist[p_b[:, 1].astype(int), p_b[:, 0].astype(int)].sum()

 chamfer_dist = 0.5 * (chamfer(p_a, p_b, image_shape) + chamfer(p_b, p_a, image_shape)
```

Another option is to use [Hausdorff Distance](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/de1/classcv_1_1HausdorffDistanceExtractor.html) which is considered in some respects to better

Comment: The chamfer distance transform is an efficient algorithm to compute the distance transform in a discrete, regular grid.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I have an efficient implementation of the TEASAR skeletonization algorithm using the exact euclidean distance transform here: https://github.com/seung-lab/kimimaro